Where does Draupadi's taunt of Duryodhana ("a blind man's son is blind") come from?
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IKFtuHnzirQ
Mahabharata scholar Ami Ganatra says it is not in authorized versions of Mahabharata.

It is fake said I didn't find it in Mahabharata
